# Is there a way to redirect an http request to https locally on win 7

Tags: windows-7, http, redirection

Just to make it clear upfront: this is not a question about server settings!

I have looked at most (all) of similar questions here.

I have an app which has hardcoded access to http: Currently the app can't be changed.

The server has closed the http: service and provides only https:. Can't change this either.

This is not a problem for brwosers, as those automatically redirect to the https:

Now I understand that I can redirect via the hosts-file to a different destination server, so redirect to another server. But this doesn't solve the issue either is it's on the same server (at least I can't think of a way).

So the question is: Is there at least one way to redirect an http: request from an application to an https: on the same server, without changing the application (javascript) or the server.

Any hints welcome.

Win is win 7-64 Home.

Comment: No. You might be able to use a fancy proxy setup or similar but honestly it's just a bad idea. If the application is just JS it should be rather easy to change?

Comment: Thx. It's a win 7-Gadget which is not supported/maintained anymore, which is obfuscated and scrambled. It would be easy to replace the http by an https (adding the s), but how to get back

Answer (score 1):

Using [stunnel](https://www.stunnel.org) in combination with [modifying the hosts file](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/) to point to localhost (127.0.0.1) might work.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting idea. I have read through it, an it does not seen to be that simple. And one question arose to me: Would it also work to redirect a http request from the local client to the https port for just one specific remote server ? It's not about all traffice to be redirected. Just one request. It's just http://earthquake.usgs.gov/ has been switched to https://earthquake.usgs.gov/. The browser can handle this, but not the gadget.

Comment: If you enter `earthquake.usgs.gov 127.0.0.1` in the hosts file, and configure stunnel to forward requests from the http port to 23.61.213.202:443, it should work.. (That IP is at least what my computer says that the DNS name resolves to. It might not work forever, and can be located in europe, since I am in Sweden) :)

Comment: Also note that you won't be able to browse to the site via the browser, unless you also setup stunnel to forward requests for the 443 port, since the domain name will point to localhost.. It will also warn about invalid certificates and such..

Comment: Ok, thks @Magnus.  It seems thats to complicated for something just for curiosity (Earthquakes Meter). But interessting solution for possible more important issues.